# Inject controls in derived windows breaks xaml markup in combination with binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am trying to inject a LayoutGrid and a canvas into my windows, but this causes a little headache:

Here is my **WindowBase** class:

```
public class WindowBase : Window
{
    protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInitialized(e);

        if (Content is FrameworkElement)
        {
            var originalContent = Content as FrameworkElement;
            var grid = new Grid();
            grid.DataContext = originalContent.DataContext;
            Content = grid;
            grid.Children.Add(originalContent);

            var canvas = new Canvas() { HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch, VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch };
            grid.Children.Add(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

My **MainWindow** thats inheriting from **WindowBase** looks like this:

**XAML:**

```
<local:WindowBase x:Class="InsertCanvasTest.MainWindow"
                  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:InsertCanvasTest"
                  DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Border>
        <Grid>
            <ComboBox SelectedIndex="1"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding ItemSource1}" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</local:WindowBase>
```

**Code Behind of MainWindow:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : WindowBase
{
    private List<int> _itemSource1;
    public List<int> ItemSource1
    {
        get
        {
            if (_itemSource1 == null)
                _itemSource1 = new List<int>(){1,2,3};
            return _itemSource1;
        }

    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

As you can see in my XAML I have specified that the `SelectedIndex` should be `1`, but with the code in my `WindowBase` where I am trying to inject the Canvas and the Grid this information gets lost and the SelectedIndex is at `-1`.

Is there a way to fix this?

I would like to keep the `MainWindow` as a `Window` and not implement it as a control and load this into some different Window inside a ContentPresenter of so.

I know this problem wouldnt exist if I declared the Canvas/Grid in the XAML directly instead of trying to inject it in codebehind, but doing this with 100+ windows and trying to maintain them if something changes is annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your WindowBase class like that :

**WindowBase**

```
[ContentProperty("InternalContent")]
public class WindowBase : Window
{
    // InternalContent
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InternalContentProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register( "InternalContent", typeof(object),
        typeof(WindowBase), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

    public object InternalContent
    {
        get { return GetValue(InternalContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InternalContentProperty, value); }
    }

    ...
}

<Window ...>
    <Grid>
        ...
        <ContentControl IsTabStop="false"
            Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, Path=InternalContent}" />
        <Canvas />
        ...
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In essence, what it does is to create a new `InternalContent` property that subclasses will see as the default content (thanks to `ContentPropertyAttribute`), and display that content with a `ContentControl`.

That said, there is most likely better ways to do what you're trying to do than inheritance. Using templates comes to mind. Or maybe [Adorners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if what you want is an "above all layer to display things" like your `Canvas` suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your problem is the setting of Content property of your Superclass Window to a "new" grid and then inserting the original content into that grid.

Where I think the problem may be is that you are setting the variable originalContent equal to Content BUT Content is an Object meaning it's a Reference Type. Problem shown below

```
var originalContent = Content as FrameworkElement;
//Reference Type: originalContent POINTS AT Content;
var grid = new Grid();

Content = grid;
//Reference Type: Content POINTS AT grid vsv. originalContent now POINTS AT grid
// Now because of Pointers and Reference Types
// originalContent = grid
```

If you want to preserve the Original Content in your Window Base Class using the Code you've shared, you would need to clone the control and use that reference in 
`var originalContent = CLONE OF CONTENT`.

Answer (score 1):

your variable originalContent has a parent and so kannt be added to a new Frameworkelement. You must remove originalContent from the old parent before you add it to a new one.

Comment: The above code is working no errors are thrown, so I am not sure what you are talking about? Maybe you can provide some Code how it would solve my problem?

Comment: Sorry, wrong answer. But I know this problem from my Silverlight project. SelectedIndex Property is set to -1 on DataContextChange. In the Line `Content = grid;` your Combox is removed from the VisualTree and loosing it's DataContex. Try Binding the SelectedIndex Property to a new Property in your WindowClass and don't allow the Setter of your new Property setting the value while in OnInitialize.